# Reference request about Thm which use Transversality to compute Homotopy Groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

I'm following the following [notes](http://wwwmath.uni-muenster.de/u/jeber_02/skripten/bordism-skript.pdf), and my attention was caught by Theorem $1.1.4$. I am unable to find any reference of the proof. Could you suggest me some books in which there is a proof of this theorem?

Comment: It's an immediate corollary of the previous theorem. Make a map from a sphere transverse to $g$; so it misses the image of $g$. This shows the map is surjective. Now given any homotopy between two maps from spheres, you can make this transverse to $g$, so that the homotopy lies entirely outside the image of $g(N)$, so the map is injective. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1344164/98602) answer for more details.

Comment: @MikeMiller thanks for the answer, everything is clear apart of the needs of the codimension $\geq k+2$ for the pointed homotopy to have the reasoning working. Could you elaborate a little more this detail?

Comment: If $f(M) and $g(N)$ are transverse in $X$ and $\dim M + \dim N < \dim X$, then their images are disjoint. This is what you want! In this case replace $M$ by $M\times I$. Hence $>k+1$.

Comment: ah, ok so that was so easy! I thought it was something to do with the fact that homotopies has to be pointed, but only now I realise that the new homotopy will preserve base point as well. So thank you!

Comment: Oh, right, I should say something about basepoints: because the map is already transverse near the basepoint, when you modify the map, you can do so without changing what it does near the basepoint.

Comment: yes, I realise just now that we can do that :-)